# Variable contains nil value in Swift 2

Tags: variables, parse-platform, swift2

I declared a variable *destinationID* on top of my class. The first print shows the right content of the variable while the second one has a nil value.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
import UIKit    

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate{

var destinationUserID = String()


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){


        //Opzoeken wat het bijhorende ID is
        let query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo:selectedUsername)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            // Do something with the found object
            for object in objects! {
               self.destinationUserID = object.objectId!
              print(self.destinationUserID)
            }
            print("try 1 : " + self.destinationUserID)
        }
         print("try 2 : " + self.destinationUserID)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `print("try 1...` statement is inside the block. The `print("try 2...` is outside the block. The block is executed in the background which means that the search might not have completed when you get to `print("try 2...`.